# Xcode - How to fix this duplicate symbols error when using MobileVLCKit

Tags: ios, xcode, h.264, vlc, libvlc

I am using two frameworks - MobileVLCKit and TTXSDK (https://github.com/tongtianxing/ios_cmsv6demo) for playing h264 stream  in my project which results in duplicate symbols error while building the project. I need to use both these frameworks. Please suggest a way to resolve the duplicate symbols error.

Comment: Can you share the exact errors? Are you using DWARF format?

Comment: DWARF with dysm

Comment: duplicate symbol 'base64Encode(char const*, unsigned int)' in:
    /ios/Pods/MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.framework/MobileVLCKit(Base64.o)
   /ios/TTXSDK.framework/TTXSDK(Base64.o)
duplicate symbol '_av_strlcpy' in:
    /ios/TTXSDK.framework/TTXSDK(avstring.o)
   ios/Pods/MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.framework/MobileVLCKit(avstring.o)
220 more errors like these.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot statically link the same code twice (FFmpeg / libavcodec here). This is the expected behavior. Consider using a single libavcodec binary only or link either TTXSDK or MobileVLCKit dynamically to work-around.

Comment: If these libraries use some of the same object files then the only work around is to remove those files from one of the libraries, which is "fiddly".

Comment: "fiddly" is a nice way of putting it indeed :)